# Making XForms enforce the constraint and type model item properties only when field is populated

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have a simple XForm with an input field where I have specified the field to be optional  with the required="false()" property.  However, I would like add a type and constraint property to the field to enforce an integer type and that the integer must be greater than 10, but only if data is entered in the field; after all, the field is optional.  For example:

```
<xf:bind nodeset="testGreaterThanTen"
         required="false()"
         type="xs:integer"
         constraint=". &gt; 10"/>
```

I would have thought the required="false()" would trump the type and constraint properties, but I appear to be wrong; it appears that including the type and constraint forces the field to be filled out.  Is this the proper behavior per the XForms 1.1 specification?  Is there anyway to do what I want in XForms?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `type="xforms:integer"` instead of `type="xs:integer"`. Orbeon supports the [XForms 1.1 types](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#intro-diffs-datatypes-mips) this way since 2007 (see the [Release Notes for Orbeon Forms 3.6](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/release-notes/36#TOC-Noteworthy-changes), fourth point of "Noteworthy Changes" and [issue #307162](http://forge.ow2.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=307162&group_id=168&atid=350207)).

Comment: yes i agree. xs:integer will show field as invalid unless there is some value entered.