# XForms relation of 'constraint' and 'required' properties

Tags: constraints, orbeon, xforms, required

As a reference, the most similar question already asked is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8667849/making-xforms-enforce-the-constraint-and-type-model-item-properties-only-when-fi The difference is that I cannot use the 'relevant' property since I do want the field to be visible and accessible.

I'm attempting to make an XForms form that has the following properties:

1. It displays a text field named 'information'. (for the example)
2. This field must not be **required**, since it may not be necessary to enter data. (Or this data will be entered at a later time.)
3. However, if data is entered in this field, it must adhere to the specified **constraint**.
4. I cannot mark the field as not **relevant** since this would hide the field and some data may need to be entered in it.

The trouble now is that even though the field has no data in it, the constraint is still enforced (i.e. even though it is not marked as 'required').

I have taken a look at the [XForms 1.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/2009/REC-xforms-20091020/#model-prop-constraint), however it does not seem to describe how the properties 'required' and 'constraint' should interact.

The only option I see, is to add a part to the constraint such that an empty value is allowed.
e.g.:

> . = '' or <actual-constraint>

However, I don't like this. It feels like a workaround to add this to every such field.

Is there any other way to express that non-required fields should not need to match the constraint for that field? (Am I missing something?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XForms 1.1, `required` serves two purposes:

1. mark the field as required (implementations can style controls to reflect this, e.g. with a "*")
2. take part in the validation process

The latter is described in [4.3.3 The xforms-revalidate Event](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11/#evt-revalidate).

> An instance node is valid if and only if the following conditions hold:

And one of the conditions is:

> the value is non-empty if the required model item property is true

So it is a logical `and` between all aspects that impact validation.

I can see how things could have been different, e.g. saying `required="false()"` could disable the rest of the validation. However that's not the approach XForms is taking.

Based on this there is nothing wrong checking for emptiness as part of the constraint.

XForms 2.0 might add custom XPath functions, which might help with reuse of logic:

```
<bind ref="information" constraint="my:constraint(.)">
```

Also, if the constraint can be expressed with a type, you may be able to use one of the [schema types in the XForms namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#empty-content-types), which allow empty values to be valid. For instance `xforms:double` considered the empty string and `42` to be valid values, but not `gaga`.

Comment: Okay, so these datatypes allow for empty-string values. That's good to know. What I would have expected is for required="false()" that it does not completely ignore the specified constraint, but instead allows for an "empty" answer, since there's no other way to indicate that you're not intending to answer the question. Of course, if an answer is given it should be within the constraints specified. Otherwise, there's no guarantee that you'll get valid data from the form.
Anyways, I now have multiple ways to achieve my goal :)